# Firebase AngularFire $save unwanted result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase, angularfire

What I am trying to achieve is to allow forms previously created to be editable and updated.

For example I would like to change the property `division:` value from `"Mens"` to `"Womens"` but this is the result I get.

Firebase database before code update.

```
// from https://myapp.firebaseio.com/seasons/-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW

-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW
    └ aaaCreatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ aaaUpdatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ division: "Mens"
    └ ...
```

Firebase database after code update.

```
// from https://myapp.firebaseio.com/seasons/-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW

-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW
    └ aaaCreatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ aaaUpdatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ division:
        └ division: "Womens"
    └ ...
```

I would like it to be like the following.

```
-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW
    └ aaaCreatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ aaaUpdatedOn: 1449611877062
    └ division: "Womens"
    └ ...
```

The url where the form is being updated is localhost/sport/app/#/update/season/-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW

Code from my controller.

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('sportApp')
        .controller('CreateSeasonController',
                    ['$routeParams', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', 'FIREBASE_URL',
                    function($routeParams, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URL) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.whichSeason = $routeParams.sid;

            var seasonUpdateRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'seasons/' + vm.whichSeason);
            var seasonUpdateArray = $firebaseArray(seasonUpdateRef);
            var seasonUpdateObject = $firebaseObject(seasonUpdateRef);

            // Populates form with data from https://myapp.firebaseio.com/seasons/-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW
            seasonUpdateObject.$loaded().then(function() {
                vm.name = seasonUpdateObject.name;
                vm.league = seasonUpdateObject.league;
                vm.division = seasonUpdateObject.division;
                vm.level = seasonUpdateObject.level;
                vm.weekday = seasonUpdateObject.weekday;
                vm.seasonal = seasonUpdateObject.seasonal;
                vm.year = seasonUpdateObject.year;
                vm.numberOfGame = seasonUpdateObject.numberOfGame;
                vm.startDate = new Date(seasonUpdateObject.startDate);
                vm.endDate = new Date(seasonUpdateObject.endDate);
            });

            vm.update = function() {
                seasonUpdateArray[2].division = vm.division;
                seasonUpdateArray.$save(2).then(function(ref) {
                    vm.message = 'Season ' + vm.name + ' was updated successfully';
                });
            };

        }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use `$loaded()` here, `$firebaseObject()` takes care triggering the `$digest()` loop when the data is loaded.

Also, you're still using `$firebaseArray()`, but not using it.

```
var seasonUpdateRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'seasons/' + vm.whichSeason);
var seasonUpdateObject = $firebaseObject(seasonUpdateRef);
vm.season = seasonUpdateObject;
```

So rather than hand assigning each field you can simply just assign the entire `$firebaseObject()` to `vm`. When the data loads, `$digest()` will update the page.

Here's a neat trick you can use for Firebase reference injection.

```
.constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase);
.factory('Season', function($firebaseObject, rootRef) {
  return function Season(season) {
    return $firebaseObject(rootRef.child(season));
  }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($routeParams, Season) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.whichSeason = $routeParams.sid;
  vm.season = Season(vm.whichSeason);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Instead of using `$firebaseArray` use `$firebaseObject`.

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('sportApp')
        .controller('CreateSeasonController',
                    ['$routeParams', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', 'FIREBASE_URL',
                    function($routeParams, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URL) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.whichSeason = $routeParams.sid;

            var seasonUpdateRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'seasons/' + vm.whichSeason);
            var seasonUpdateArray = $firebaseArray(seasonUpdateRef);
            var seasonUpdateObject = $firebaseObject(seasonUpdateRef);

            // Populates form with data from https://myapp.firebaseio.com/seasons/-K52aSeDHqvBVlg4KRSW
            seasonUpdateObject.$loaded().then(function() {
                vm.name = seasonUpdateObject.name;
                vm.league = seasonUpdateObject.league;
                vm.division = seasonUpdateObject.division;
                vm.level = seasonUpdateObject.level;
                vm.weekday = seasonUpdateObject.weekday;
                vm.seasonal = seasonUpdateObject.seasonal;
                vm.year = seasonUpdateObject.year;
                vm.numberOfGame = seasonUpdateObject.numberOfGame;
                vm.startDate = new Date(seasonUpdateObject.startDate);
                vm.endDate = new Date(seasonUpdateObject.endDate);
            });

            vm.update = function() {

                seasonUpdateObject.aaaUpdatedOn = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                seasonUpdateObject.name = vm.name;
                seasonUpdateObject.league = vm.league;
                seasonUpdateObject.division = vm.division;
                seasonUpdateObject.level = vm.level;
                seasonUpdateObject.weekday = vm.weekday;
                seasonUpdateObject.seasonal = vm.seasonal;
                seasonUpdateObject.year = vm.year;
                seasonUpdateObject.numberOfGame = vm.numberOfGame;
                seasonUpdateObject.startDate = vm.startDate.toString();
                seasonUpdateObject.endDate = vm.endDate.toString();

                seasonUpdateObject.$save().then(function(ref) {
                    vm.message = 'Season ' + vm.name + ' was updated successfully';
                });
            };

        }]);
})();
```